# Get Day by Day UsageStats with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, usagestatsmanager

I am working on an application that displays Usage Stats for applications used on an android device. What I am trying to specifically do is chunk out usage time by day. So essentially, the end goal is to have a bar chart and each column is a total day's usage time.

I have implemented Usage

```
private long getWeekStartTime() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Set it to 7 days prior
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}

private long getEndTime(){
        // Set end time to Now
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void retrieveWeekUsageStats(){
        List<UsageStats> usageStats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(INTERVAL_DAILY,getWeekStartTime(), getEndTime());

        for (UsageStats stat: usageStats) {
            Log.d(TAG, "retrieveWeekUsageStats: " + stat.getPackageName() + " " + stat.getFirstTimeStamp() +" " + stat.getLastTimeStamp());
        }
}
```

With the above code, I am able to log out a ton of packages that have been used recently but all of the packages and dates are intermixed.

I set the interval in the UsageStatsManager to INTERVAL_DAILY with the hopes that it would separate out the package uses into day intervals but it just spits everything out in a random order. What is the best way to sort this list into chunks by day?

I also tried to adjust the INTERVAL_DAILY to INTERVAL_WEEKLY with no avail.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61816502/10325630) answer your question?