# How can I get my app screen time on a hourly basis?

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

Android's UsageStatsManager returning data for minimum one day, but I want to get accurate data from 12 am to the current time. I tried several types but nothing works properly. The "Action Dash" and "Digital Wellbeing" is getting data accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [queryEvents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager#queryEvents(long,%20long)) method of [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager) class.

I've recently built an app for tracking daily app usage. Firstly, I tried using [queryUsageStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager#queryUsageStats(int,%20long,%20long)) but it didn't work properly. I thought it was supposed to return usage time from 12 am to current time when [INTERVAL_DAILY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager#INTERVAL_DAILY) is passed to it, but instead it was returning something else. Maybe there is a bug or there is something wrong on my side related to time zone or something.

Anyway, then I tried *queryEvents* and it worked fine.

Here's my [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677505/how-to-count-app-usage-time-while-app-is-on-foreground) (See both the question and the accepted answer).